# Trying to compile LESS to CSS but throwing an error

Tags: css, npm, less

I am trying to compile `$lessc styles.less styles.css`

But getting an error with the message from the compiler:

> $ParseError: Unrecognised input. Possibly missing something in C:\Users\james\Documents\Web-Projects\2022\mod-1\styles.less on line 79, column 1:
> 78
> 79

```
#carouselButton {
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you show a piece of code around 78 and 79 lines?
Also remove second slash before `styles.less`

Comment: Do not paste code as an image in your answer, as if the link dies then so does the question and an future readers will not understand what question the answers solve.  That can't be all the code in that file.  The error is on line 79 and there's only 5 lines of code there.

Comment: It could just be because of a missing semi-colon in the style.